# Jest withtout rxjs-compat

Tags: angular, rxjs, package, jestjs, compatibility

As Rxjs 6.x is out for a while now I'm trying to get rid of the rxjs-compat module.
Everything is going well at compilation but not when I launch my tests.

I got the error :

```
Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/add/observable/of' from 'of.js'

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:203:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/of.js:3:1)
```

Everything i get from googling that error is about modifying the imports, but those lines are not my code (i think)

Note that it is only happening with my angular project.

I'm using rxjs: 6.4.0 and jest 24.1.0 
Angular 7.1.3 and jest-preset-angular latest.

Do I have to change something in my config ?
Or is simply Jest not ready for pure rxjs 6